# Why does Blasphemy destroy undead which are generally evil?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, undead, alignment

I was reading the spell [Blasphemy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blasphemy/) and its got contradictory texts/

Its area for example says

> Area nonevil creatures in a 40-ft.-radius spread centered on you

Then the spell effects

> Killed: Living creatures die. Undead creatures are destroyed. Save negates. If the save is successful, the creature instead takes 3d6 points of damage + 1 point per caster level (maximum +25).

The [subtype page](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#TOC-Undead) for undead clearly mentions they are evil (howeve there is one case that is not evil, but juju undead are not part of this question)

> Undead are invariably evil, as are the means to create such beings.

So since the spell isnt supposed to hurt evil things, why are undead destroyed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Because it's possible for undead to be of non-evil alignment

While it is true that undead, in general, are all of evil alignment, that is a general rule, and as such, exceptions are allowed. For instance, [Ghosts](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/ghost/) can be of any alignment, even Lawful Good ([example](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/npc-s/npcs-cr-13/half-orc-ghost-oracle/)).

A [shadowdancer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/shadowdancer/)'s shadow companion will match the character's alignment:

> Unlike a normal shadow, this shadow’s alignment matches that of the shadowdancer, and the creature cannot create spawn.

It is also possible for any undead to become non-evil if they happen to wear a [Helm of Opposite Alignment](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic-items/cursed-items/#Helm_of_Opposite_Alignment).

But before Pathfinder existed, there were non-evil undead as well, in *Forgotten Realms* we had the [Baelnorn](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Baelnorn_lich), elven liches of non-evil alignment (mostly lawful neutral or lawful good).

As such, that line is there to handle these special cases.

Answer (score 5):

*Blasphemy* does nothing to evil creatures—living or undead. It only affects non-evil creatures. Just as “Living creatures die,” applies only to those living creatures that the spell affects, that is, non-evil ones, “Undead creatures are destroyed,” applies only to those undead creatures that are affected in the first place, which again are the non-evil ones. Which is a rare thing for the undead but not actually impossible—and even if it was, a future exception could always be written, so *blasphemy* should account for that.